# How to bind IObservableSet to IObservableList?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have an instance of `IObservableList`, I'd like to observe its values with `IObservableSet` interface, by either binding or wrapping.

Is there already implemented solution? Should I write one?

Answer (score 3):

There is a [org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.set.ListToSetAdapter](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/databinding/observable/set/ListToSetAdapter.html).